# How to use image instead of box-shadow to achieve similar effect?

Tags: css

I want to achieve the box shadow effect as shown in the image below:

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpqGM.png)

**However I do not want to use css3 `box-shadow` property.** (This is because I am building a phonegap android application and it has lag problems when using `box-shadow`.)

Can anyone guide me on how I can make use of images or some other technique to come up with a div styling as shown in the image above. Code will be much helpful as I am not a CSS expert.

**For info:**

The css3 code which renders the above div is as follows:

```
.drop-shadow {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 2em 10px 4em;
    background: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
```

Comment: do you need the buttons to dynamically re-size depending on the content (text) of the button? that will effect how you build the button.

Comment: Yes. I do need dynamic resizing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the older techniques to achieve this effect:

- [Offset Shadow](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/shadow2.html)
- [Wrapped Shadow](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/shadow3.html)
- [Image Shadow](http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/image-shadow-background.htm)