# box shadow not working in Android

Tags: android, css, cordova

Im trying to set box-shadow on a div. I have:

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.9);
```

This works fine on a desktop browser. But when I run the app through Phonegap in Android 4.3, nothing is rendered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only android 2.3 needs a -webkit prefix. Try with it.

Comment: i have -webkit prefix...

Comment: Oh, I wanted to say WITHOUT it, sorry

Comment: Check this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242787/how-to-use-image-instead-of-box-shadow-to-achieve-similar-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small offtop: box-shadow has very poor performance when theres more items with it (at least on android). I've been optimising css once for phonegap app and removing it had made great difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android Browser does not support the "inset", try to omit it.

> Android Browser refers to missing "inset" and blur radius value support.

from http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow